# In a Cloud Function, what syntax is used for writing to a Firestore sub-collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Assuming we have a chat application that has a database structure that looks similar to this:

[image]

I know writing to the rooms collection would look like this:

`await admin.firestore().collection("rooms").doc(roomA).set()`

Would writing to the messages collection look like this?

`await admin.firestore().collection("rooms").doc(roomA).collection(messages).doc(message1).set()`

And just follow this structure all the way down, collection.doc.collection.doc.collection.doc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that operation will a sub-document with ID `message1` (you missed the quotes though). If you want to add a new document to sub-collection with a random ID, you can use `add()`:

```
await admin.firestore().collection("rooms").doc('roomId').collection(messages).add({...data})
```

Alternatively, you can also write the path to that sub-document as:

```
await admin.firestore().doc('rooms/roomId/messages/messageId').set(...)
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I missed the quotes: .doc(roomA) should be .doc("roomA") and so forth